# Issue in deleting vector from Faiss index

Tags: python, embedding, openai-api, langchain, faiss

I used remove_ids method to remove some vectors from faiss index, After deleting a vectory , search result are very incorrect. Anybody have some information regarding this? how can i correctly delete vector from faiss index without effecting search result

Followig is the code that i used to remove id

```
import numpy as np
import faiss
index = faiss.read_index('index.faiss')
ids_to_remove=[1]
ids_to_remove_array=np.array(ids_to_remove,dtype=np.int64)
index.remove_ids(ids_to_remove_array)
faiss.write_index(index,'index.faiss')
```

Answer (score 2):

Different Faiss index types handle the removal of vectors differently. It's crucial to understand the nuances associated with removing vectors from various index types to ensure the stability and accuracy of search results.

Here's a breakdown of how different index types handle the removal operation:

1. Sequential indexes (IndexFlat, IndexPQ, IndexLSH)

The removal operation shifts the ids of vectors above the removed vector id.

2. IndexIVF and IndexIDMap2

Store the ids of vectors explicitly, so the ids of other vectors are not changed. There are two special cases for IndexIVF:

- DirectMap type Array does not support removal because it means that all the indices would be shifted, which does not seem very useful.
- with a direct map type Hashtable and a selector IDSelectorArray elements can be removed without scanning the whole index.

So If preserving the IDs of search results is a critical requirement, it is recommended to utilize IndexIVF or IndexIDMap2. It's important to note that the removal of vectors can potentially alter search results. This can occur because deletions may impact the neighbors of cells or even disrupt specific structural components within the index.

Additionaly you can use this for removal:

```py
def delete(remove_set, index, new_index_path):
    '''
    Parameters
    remove_set : numpy.ndarray 

    Eg: 
    remove_set = np.array([10, 30], dtype=np.int64)  
    remove_set = np.array([30], dtype=np.int64)

    index: Faiss index
    '''
    index.remove_ids(remove_set)
    print(f"Remove ids ----> {remove_set}")
    faiss.write_index(index, new_index_path)
    return index
```

Take a look the original scripts : [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/tests/test_index_composite.py#L25)